# pyinstaller error when trying to import urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, pyinstaller

I have some simple python code and it works fine from the interpreter, but when I try to import `urllib2` and package it with pyinstaller, I get the following error:

```
root@localhost:/root# ./test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "requests/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cgi.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "io.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: /tmp/_MEIgQLoAL/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt
test returned -1
```

Python code example :

```
import urllib2
read = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
print read
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you on Linux, or Windows?  What version of Python and what version of pyinstaller are you using?

Comment: @StevenByrne on Linux - Ubuntu. Python v2.7.10. pyinstaller v 3.1.1.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps at all: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/82